# Pandas - How to remove digits after the dot

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I need your help - how can I remove the digits after the dot?

[image: this is the plot]

And another thing - where do I need to write the 'rename' in order to change the number of months to their names?

[image]

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set the index as type `int` instead.

```
df.plot(figsize=(8, 8), xticks=df.index)
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: like this?
df_posts ['Year_created'] = df_posts['CreationDate'].dt.year
df_posts ['Month_created'] = df_posts['CreationDate'].dt.month

pst_pivot = df_posts.pivot_table(index='Year_created', columns='Month_created', values='Title', aggfunc='count')

pst_pivot_nan=pst_pivot.fillna(0)

pst_pivot_nan.index = pst_pivot_nan.index.astype(int)

pst_pivot_nan.head()

pst_pivot_nan.plot(figsize=(8,8))

Because it is still showing me the numbers after the dot

Comment: Hey I modified the answer. You can try it out. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

after filling `nan` values:-

```
pst_pivot_nan=pst_pivot.fillna(0)
```

Just change the `dtype` of **pst_pivot_nan** from `float` to `int` by using `astype()` method:-

```
pst_pivot_nan=pst_pivot_nan.astype(int)
```

Now finally:-

```
pst_pivot_nan.plot(figsize=(8,8))
```

**Edit:**

If you are again having this same problem then just pass `xticks` parameter in `plot()` method:-

```
pst_pivot_nan.plot(figsize=(8,8),xticks=pst_pivot_nan.index)
```

Output of above code:-

[image]

Comment: I'ts still showing the numbers after the dot ):

Comment: can you post a part of your dataframe?

Comment: sure, It is in the post now

Comment: can you post the output of this code:-`pst_pivot_nan.to_dict()` so that I can create an exact same copy of your dataframe

Comment: {1: {2011: 0, 2012: 92, 2013: 129},
 2: {2011: 0, 2012: 72, 2013: 99},
 3: {2011: 0, 2012: 62, 2013: 107},
 4: {2011: 0, 2012: 88, 2013: 92},
 5: {2011: 0, 2012: 93, 2013: 130},
 6: {2011: 0, 2012: 105, 2013: 120},
 7: {2011: 0, 2012: 105, 2013: 134},
 8: {2011: 0, 2012: 81, 2013: 143},
 9: {2011: 0, 2012: 60, 2013: 64},
 10: {2011: 1, 2012: 75, 2013: 0},
 11: {2011: 15, 2012: 77, 2013: 0},
 12: {2011: 140, 2012: 155, 2013: 0}}

Comment: Edited my answer kindly have a look